# No image shown in Blogdown Addins insert image with resizing

Tags: r, blogdown

I tried to insert an image in an Rmd file by using the Addins from blogdown and I can resize the image.

When I insert the image without any resizing, it works and the code is as follow;

```
![](/post/image1.png)
```

However, when I modify the code to resize, it fails and keeps the same size of the image with the extra part of code I added as text. Here are the codes I tried.

```
![](/post/image1.png){height="200" width=60% }
```

```
![](/post/image1.png){height="200" width=60%}
```

```
![](/post/image1.png){ height="200" width=60% }
```

```
![](/post/image1.png) {height="200" width=60% }
```

On the other hand, when I use the Addins and input the size, no images are shown at all. Here is the code.

```
<img src="/post/image1.png" alt="" width="50%"/>
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a reproducible example. In particular, I don't know which file format you were using. The syntax `![](/post/image1.png){height="200" width=60%}` only works for `.Rmd` posts. It won't work for `.md` or `.Rmarkdown`. For more information about these formats, please see: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html